# How to prevent Firebase Analytics from reporting if the cookie policy is not accepted

Tags: firebase, cookies, firebase-analytics

My web app is logging Firebase Analytic events but if the user chooses not to accept the Cookie Policy how do I then tell Firebase not to write a cookie and log the events?